# MikroORM refuses to connect to postgres in docker container

Tags: typescript, docker, discord.js, mikro-orm

MikroORM is saying `MikroORM failed to connect to database postgres on postgresql://postgres:*****@127.0.0.1:5432` for some reason when in a docker container. It isn't clear about what went wrong during the connection process.
Here are some relevant files:
docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_DB
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  app:
    build: .
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - app-data:/app/data
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env

volumes:
  app-data: {}
  db-data: {}
```

mikro-orm.config.ts

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { User } from "./entities/user";

export default {
  entities: [User],
  migrations: {
    path: './migrations', // path to the folder with migrations
    pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/, // regex pattern for the migration files
  },
  type: "postgresql",
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  dbName: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  debug: true,
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

Also my logs

```
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2021-01-15 00:37:58.161 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1   | 2021-01-15 00:37:58.162 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-01-15 00:37:58.162 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-01-15 00:37:58.165 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2021-01-15 00:37:58.172 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-01-15 00:37:39 UTC
db_1   | 2021-01-15 00:37:58.181 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app_1  | 
app_1  | > bot@1.0.0 start
app_1  | > tsc && node dist/index.js
app_1  | 
app_1  | [discovery] ORM entity discovery started, using ReflectMetadataProvider
app_1  | [discovery] - processing entity User
app_1  | [discovery] - entity discovery finished, found 1 entities, took 49 ms
app_1  | [info] MikroORM failed to connect to database postgres on postgresql://postgres:*****@127.0.0.1:5432
```

Comment: Seeing `POSTGRES_HOST: db` in your compose file, my guess is you should adjust your ORM config to use that host too.

Comment: My `POSTGRES_HOST` in my .env is `POSTGRES_DB=postgres`. Client url becomes `postgresql://postgres:fsr@postgres:5432/postgres`. Still refuses to connect. here are db logs. ```db_1   | 2021-01-13 16:36:34.866 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2021-01-13 16:36:34.866 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432``` I have tried 0.0.0.0 as the host but doesn't work

Comment: I made some changes to my program to attempt to make it fuction @MartinAdámek

Comment: Well you can clearly see your database it not started from the `2021-01-15 00:37:58.172 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-01-15 00:37:39 UTC`

Comment: I always assumed that that meant that was the last shutdown and it started up again, ill look into it. I can run commands inside the database and it seems to be up. thanks for helping me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding a link from one container to the next. By adding the line

```
    links:
        - "db:db"
```

to the `app` container, I was able to connect